# Sort an json array based on regex match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json array called **attachments** where I need to sort based on **sort_based_on_this_order** array.

```
var sort_based_on_this_order = ['1666432801510', '1666434048280', '1666433926644', '1666434169913', '1666433101760', '1666434194815', '1666432849037', '1666432764144', '1666432044571', '1666432742444']
```

sort_based_on_this_order array contains the filename key value of attachments json array

```
var attachments = [
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978911/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433926644.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978911
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978910/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434169913.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978910
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978909/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434048280.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978909
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978907/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433101760.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978907
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978905/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434194815.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978905
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978904/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432849037.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978904
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978903/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432801510.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978903
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978902/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432764144.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978902
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978901/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432044571.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978901
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978900/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432742444.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978900
                }
            ]
```

I have tried with

```
attachments.sort.forEach(zz => {
                return zz["filename"].match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code to sort it

```
attachments.sort((a,b) =>{
   let k1 = a.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
   let k2 = b.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
   let i1 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k1[0])
   let i2 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k2[0])
   return i1 > i2 ? 1:-1
})
```

```js
var attachments = [
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978911/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433926644.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978911
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978910/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434169913.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978910
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978909/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434048280.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978909
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978907/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666433101760.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978907
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978905/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666434194815.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978905
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978904/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432849037.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978904
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978903/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432801510.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978903
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978902/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432764144.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978902
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978901/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432044571.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978901
                },
                {
                   
                    "download_small_url": "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/ajDWYWQoe9Gw6WAnK8H4fG/data/194338021/attachments/82978900/",
                    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
                    "filename": "deploymentsmaster/attachments/a46854ceb37c4e55b4a2c5ea565c4ebf/04ac3197-7d0f-4301-bbaf-68daaee2b1a8/1666432742444.jpg",
                    "instance": 194338021,
                    "xform": 740320,
                    "id": 82978900
                }
            ]
var sort_based_on_this_order = ['1666432801510', '1666434048280', '1666433926644', '1666434169913', '1666433101760', '1666434194815', '1666432849037', '1666432764144', '1666432044571', '1666432742444']     
     
attachments.sort((a,b) =>{
   let k1 = a.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
   let k2 = b.filename.match(/\b[0-9]{13}(?=\.[^.]+$)/)
   let i1 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k1[0])
   let i2 = sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k2[0])
   return i1 > i2 ? 1:-1
})

console.log(attachments)
```

Comment: @CodeGuy if it missing,the index is null and you can assign a default value to it,such as `-1` or `-Infinity`

Comment: @CodeGuy I mean add default value to `i1`,`i2` ,then it will work,not in your original code

Comment: @CodeGuy if some items is missing,then `sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(k2[0])` will reeturn -1,and you can do further process here

Comment: @CodeGuy sure,let me check later

Comment: @CodeGuy I have posted an answer,you can check that answer

Comment: @CodeGuy could you upvote and accpet my another answer,please?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort the `attachments` array based on the `sort_based_on_this_order` array (I however don't see the values matching in both arrays, so maybe you try something else which I could not figure out?)

You can sort based on an other array by using the indexOf for the other array in  the sort.

```js
attachments.sort((a, b) => {  
  return sort_based_on_this_order.indexOf(a.fileName) - sort_based_on_this_order .indexOf(b.fileName);
});
```